# Lorentz-Transformation of Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

> In a reference system $\Sigma$ a particle has velocity $\vec{v} = v \hat{z}$. What is the velocity of the particle in a system $\Sigma'$ moving with velovity $\vec{u} = u \hat{z} $ relative to $\Sigma$?

One takes the 4-vector $v^\mu = \gamma(1,\vec{v}/c) = \gamma(1,0,0,v/c)$ and Lorentz-transforms it according to:

$$ v^{\mu '}  = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma & 0 & 0 & - \beta \gamma \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0  & 0  & 1 & 0  \\
  - \beta \gamma & 0 & 0 & \gamma 
 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
  \gamma v /c 
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  1  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
  \gamma^2 (-\beta + v / c )
 \end{pmatrix} \cong \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
  \gamma v' /c 
 \end{pmatrix}  $$

and therefore $v' = \gamma (-u + v). $

However the known formula for relativistic velocity transformations states: 
$$v' = \frac{v + u}{1 + \frac{v u }{c^2}},$$

which is not the same as above. Where did I do a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying a 4x4 matrix by a 4x1 matrix, but the gammas in 4x4 and 4x1 matrices must relate to different velocities, therefore, they are different, so how do you get gamma squared?

Comment: Thus: 
$$ v^{\mu '}  = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma & 0 & 0 & - \beta \gamma \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0  & 0  & 1 & 0  \\
  - \beta \gamma & 0 & 0 & \gamma 
 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
  1  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
   v /c 
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma - \beta \gamma v/c  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
  \gamma (-\beta + v / c )
 \end{pmatrix} \cong \begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma'  \\
  0 \\
  0  \\
  \gamma' v' /c 
 \end{pmatrix}  $$

Comment: and this gives: $\gamma' = \gamma (1 - u v /c^2)$ and thus,
$$ v' = \frac{- u + v}{1- \frac{uv}{c^2}}.$$

The minus sign of $u$ arises probably due to another sign convention, or not?

Comment: There may be a number of reasons: a sign convention, or maybe mixed up covariant and contravariant coordinates. I am sure you can sort it out yourself.

Comment: @Breaking M_a_t There are three different gamma's: in the 4x4 matrix you have $\gamma_u = (1 - u^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$, in the first 4x1 matrix there's a $\gamma_v = (1 - v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$, and in the last 4x1 matrix there's a $\gamma' = (1 - v'^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$.